# Check If file exists inside a folder of a Console Application

Tags: c#

I have a console application project in C#, inside my project I have a Image folder. I want to check if specific image exists inside that folder. If I use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory or Environment.CurrentDirectory I get the bin\Debug folder. How can I point to the Image folder? I want to make sure that this check will work when I deploy the project.

Comment: take a look at `Path.Combine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your images Copy to Output Directory property to Copy Always / Copy if newer

[image]

With this, it will be copied to the folder where the executing application resides (bin\Debug). And then you could just reference the image path

```
string imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Images");
```

Answer (score 2):

You get `bin\Debug` because the .exe is copied to that path and run from there while running in the Visual Studio debugger.  By default, image files are not copied to that folder.

If you go to the properties in Visual Studio of each image and set the Copy to Output Directory property to Copy if newer or Copy always, the images will be copied appropriately and you can open them with a relative path, e.g. "Images/My.png"

Comment: Cool so if I do File.Exists(@"Images/My.png") should work without any problem but it returns false and the image is there. I'm in debug mode right now